# Function, investment code not computing

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, return, arguments

so this is what I am suppose to do and I tried to do it but for some reason my code will validate but it does not compute correctly? Anyone know why?

```
function doFV()
function computeFutureValue(principal, annualRate, years, periodsPerYear)
```

The first function (`doFV`)

- takes no parameters
- is called from the `onclick` attribute
- gets input from the user
- calls the `computeFutureValue` function
- displays the result to the user

The second function (`computeFutureValue`) computes and returns the future value of an investment. The formula for computing the future value of an investment is:

```
f = a (1 + r)n
```

Comment: */

function doFV()

var years = parseFloat(document.getElementById("yearsBox").value)
var principal= parseFloat(document.getElementById("principalBox").value);
var annualRate= parseFloat(document.getElementById("periodsPerYear").value );
var periodsPerYear= parseFloat(document.getElementById("periodsPerYear").value);


function computeFutureValue(principal, annualRate, years, periodsPerYear)
 var years = 10
 var principal= 100
 var annualRate= 0.07
 var periodsPerYear= 4 

 var computeFutureValue = 100 (1+4)^10

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to include the definitions for the functions in question.  What are some sample inputs, actual outputs, and expected outputs?

Comment: example of principle=100 annualrate=.07 years=10 periods per year=4

function doFV()

var years = parseFloat(document.getElementById("yearsBox").value)
var principal= parseFloat(document.getElementById("principalBox").value);
var annualRate= parseFloat(document.getElementById("periodsPerYear").value );
var periodsPerYear= parseFloat(document.getElementById("periodsPerYear").value);


function computeFutureValue(principal, annualRate, years, periodsPerYear)
 var years = 10
 var principal= 100
 var annualRate= 0.07
 var periodsPerYear= 4 

 var computeFutureValue = 100 (1+4)^10